# What are the luxuries of Swarga Loka? And how Swarga Loka has been defined in the Vedas?

Tags: vedas, rebirth, heaven

Can some one fulfill his unsatisfied desires. And after enjoying in sawarg lok can one decide how he /she wants to reincarnate him/herself.reincarnation happens with our will or against our will.

Comment: There are too many questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What are the luxuries of Swarga Loka? And how Swarga Loka has been defined in the Vedas?

It is a place of material happiness. Indra loka is part of Swarga loka. Vedavya's Yoga Bhashya (Vedavyasa's commentary on Patanjali's Yoga Sutras) describes the heavens. Here is the description for Swarga:

> The inhabitants of the Mahendra (Maha Indra's loka) are the six divine
> beings...all these have an irresistible will and are endued with the
> eight mystic powers such as buoyancy and the rest. Their life span
> extends to a kalpa. **They rejoice in sexuality** and are endowed with
> bodies born without sexual intercourse. They have loving Apsaras for
> their wives.

There are other pleasures too of course, like eating, drinking, music, etc.

The stay in Swarga is only temporary. Once all his punya has been experienced in swarga, he takes birth again on Earth according to his karma.

Comment: Thanks but can you tell how many year can some live in heaven.

Comment: @DarkKnight The passage that I cited in my answer says this: "Their life span extends to a **kalpa.**" One kalpa (one day of BrahmA) is 4.32 billion years, or one thousand mahayugas..